# use chrome headless mode by ip

Tags: ip, localhost, headless

I met a question.

I use command

`/Applications/Google\ Chrome\ Canary.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome\ Canary --headless --remote-debugging-port=9222 ----remote-debugging-address=192.168.1.154`

to run chrome headless mode.

I can open "Headless Chromium" tab by `http://localhost:9222`,like this.
[image]

But the `http://192.168.1.154` can`t open it.
[image]

I`m sure my ip is 192.168.1.154 and firewall is close.

How to solve it?

Please tell me,thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your IP and localhost IP isnt the same, try it with **127.0.0.1:9222**